# Postgres extension missing after upgrade

Tags: postgresql, pgtap

I have just upgraded my development postgres cluster from postgreSQL 9.6 to 11. Everything went fine except that I got an error around the pgtap extension that I use for unit testing.

Now when I try to restore a database I'm getting an error
"ERROR: could not open extension control file "/usr/share/postgresql/11/extension/pgtap.control"

When I look in the file system I can see all the pgtap files are still in /usr/share/postgresql/9.6/extension.
I tried uninstalling pgtap running `sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove pgtap` and then re-installing but this hasn't worked, all the files are still in the 9.6 directory.

Comment: You need to install it in PG 11 too

Comment: Thanks, but I can't see anything in the docs about how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

pgTAP is a third-party extension, you won't find anything about it in the PostgreSQL manual.

You will have to install it separately in your v11 PostgreSQL installation. See [the installation instructions](https://pgtap.org/documentation.html#installation) for pgTAP.

Comment: Thanks but I've tried the things suggested in the documentation, unfortunately nothing in there has any suggestions on how to install it into a specific version of postgres.

Comment: Oh yes, it does: `env PG_CONFIG=/path/to/pg_config make`